# How do I run a simple server process on an IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I was not quite sure how to phrase this question.

What I want to do is create a simple server type application in C# which simply listens for incoming socket connections and handles them the way I specify.  It could be a chat application or something like that, very simple.

I looked at the example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx about asynchronous sockets.

I understand the code in the example except I'm uncertain about how the code would execute.  Specifically, what would be the entry point of the application in the example? How would the server know to start it?

My only experience with IIS is in web forms with C# codebehind.  I understand that the code for web forms is executed when the url points to the location and then again on postbacks etc.

Where it gets foggy for me is when I don't want to use a web form but simply a collection of C# class files with a single entry point (similar to a java application).

Edit for clarity:

The goal of what I want to do is to create an application which I can put on my web host which will continuously accept requests from client applications and handle them the way I will specify and then return information to the clients.  I'm just not sure how to tell the server to start the application since I only know about web forms.
Also, it would be fine if I needed to initially direct my browser to a web form and, say, press a button to start the application.  In fact, it would be ideal if I could start and stop the application at will.
Also, I may have used incorrect terminology.  I thought IIS servers were what you called a server which can run asp.net applications.  I could be very wrong about this.

Thanks.

Comment: It is self hosted application, it is the server itself. You don't need IIS for it.

Comment: For socket connections, I doubt you'd want to use a web server.  How about just writing an `.EXE` for now, which can later be registered as a windows service by adding a bit of code.

Comment: You are probably right, I'm not so familiar with this sort of thing but I'm not sure how to do an exe on a web host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot use IIS to start windows applications, you need a windows service application that constantly listens to the port specified, and that windows service application needs to be scheduled to start either at system start up or at any event of your choice. and that windows service applications needs to stay in memory as long as you want your app to function.

PS: your question seriously needs some editing, but I am also new to SO, so I will let respectable senior users to do what they are best at.

**EDIT:** If you want to simulate windows service using IIS than here are your closest bets, please follow the links to know what you need to know.

[Simulate Windows Service Using ASP.NET App](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)

[Forcing your Application to Stay alive](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/10/Forcing-an-ASPNET-Application-to-stay-alive)

These two links will help you keep alive your application and bamm, you can create any number of classes (Java style as you quoted) to perform whatever tasks you want it to perform

Comment: @Mason You can accomplish the task by simply creating a desktop application that has a windows service with an HttpListener, there you got your entry point to the application. links below will help you in understanding C# Windows Service creation

http://tech.pro/tutorial/895/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C

Comment: You are probably right but I don't want to run the application on my pc, I want to run it on a hosting server.  Also, could you please tell me what I need to edit in my post so I dont make the same mistake in the future?

Comment: @Mason ahaan I got your point, you have shared hosting but you need to create an application that is basically a web application but keeps itself alive using some mechanism. I will get back to you on that in a short while

Comment: @Mason about your post it vaguely present itself in the fashion of a question that is asked after a little research on the internet, you need to put in more specific requirements of the tasks that you want to accomplish

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is what I needed.  I just have one follow up question (and maybe it's more appropriate to start a new question, if so just tell me) what is "zero load" with regard to a server?  The first link uses the term but I searched and found nothing.  Thanks again

Comment: zero load means that the application has got no requests during the time period specified for the application to be drained out of memory, as a result the application is unloaded

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you don't want to use IIS at all. IIS handles the listening for you and is the "service" to manage requests. If you are lookng to manually listen for incoming connections, then you will need the following components:

1. A windows service running that has..
2. A http listener built into it.

Take a look at the C# HttpListener class and look at the process for building a window service that can run in the background of your server.

This isn't all that difficult, but I'm not so sure it's what you need. If you don't want to use webforms, you can have a web application that resolves requests straight to custom handlers which i THINK is what you're actually looking for and makes having your own listener overkill.

EDIT: Additional info on custom handlers

Here is a start on what a custom handler is and how to use it:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

I would also look at some beginner articles on MVC3 from .net. MVC is a framework that doesn't have any of the fluff (such as viewstate) that webforms has and allows you to route a URL (request) to a Controller (class) and return pretty much anything you want. There are a lot of advantages to using MVC and if you are coming from a java/pure http background it will make much more sense than webforms.

You can get started with that one by searching around for "getting started with .net MVC3" or even start with www.asp.net for beginner resources.

Comment: I mostly understand what you are saying but I guess I'm confused about windows services.  I dont want the server to run on my pc, I want to use a server from a hosting provider I already have.  I think I want what you are talking about at the end, could you please share a resource or terms I should use to search for this?  Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers because I believe this one is equally helpful as the one I accepted

Answer (score 0):

Unless your goal is to learn low level TCP communication, writing and configuring services, dealing with code changes, writing own serialization/request parsing than sticking with IIS and HTTP maybe easier approach.

There is no need to use WebForms - WebService (ASP.Net or even WCF) or [MVC Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) will give you ability to implement methods you want without need to write your own custom serialization and request parsing infrastructure. You can even do long poll if/when needed (i.e. [SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)).

I'd start with basic MVC application reporting JSON results as server side as it will still show all issues involved with writing chat client (persistence, discovery of other clients, quick status updates) while allowing you to focus on communication itself (including easily see all traffic if need).